# How to tell "grep -w" what characters make up "words"?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, search

```
$ printf 'asf .test. afd\nasaf foo-test asfdads\n'
asf .test. afd
asaf foo-test asfdads

$ printf 'asf .test. afd\nasaf foo-test asfdads\n' | grep -w test
asf .test. afd
asaf foo-test asfdads
```

**Question**: How can I match the "foo-test"? To be more precise, **how can I say to "-w" use "-" as separator, but don't use "."**?

Or in other words, can I tell `grep` that `.` is among the characters that make up *words*, and thus that there's no *word boundary* in between `.` and `test`?

Or are there other solutions than grep?

Comment: How can you match the "foo-test"? grep for "foo-test"? I'm pretty sure I don't understand your question.

Comment: I updated the Question.

Comment: But both `.` and `-` are already separators: from the manpage: "Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the underscore."

Comment: How can I say to "-w" use "-" as separator, but don't use "."?

Comment: yes, and the solution doesn't need to be in grep

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In versions prior to 2.19, GNU `grep`'s `-w` would only consider single-byte character alnums and underscore (so in UTF-8 locales, only the 26+26+10+1 (ASCII letters, digits and underscore)) as word constituents. So for instance `echo Stéphane | grep -w St` would match. That was fixed in 2.19.

You could however implement the logic by hand:

```
 grep -E '([^[:alnum:]_.]|^)test([^[:alnum:]_.]|$)'
```

That is `test` preceded by either a non-word-constituent or the beginning of the line and followed by either a non-word-constituent or the end of the line.

(above `[:alnum:]` matches digits and letters in your locale, not only ASCII ones, fix the locale to C if you want only ASCII ones).

If you don't want those surrounding non-word-constituents to be included in the match (for instance because you're using GNU's `-o`), you can this time use PCRE regexps and look-around operators:

```
grep -Po '(*UCP)(?<![\w.])test(?![\w.])'
```

Remove `(*UCP)` and add `LC_ALL=C` to match only ASCII letters and digits.

Using `(*UCP)` at the start of a regexp tells the PCRE library that *U̲niC̲ode P̲roperties* have to be used for `\w`.

Without it, `\w` would match your locale's alphanumericals and underscore but only for single-byte characters. That wouldn't work in UTF-8 locales (the norm nowadays) where only ASCII ones would be matched. `(*UCP)` makes it work for UTF-8 as well. It would match based on PCRE's own notion of character properties which might be different from your locale's, but on GNU systems, that's just as well as the UTF-8 locale definitions there are incomplete and outdated (at least as of 2015-04).