# grep in limiting

Tags: grep, yaml

I have a YAML file:

```
- name: scheduler-configuration
- name: scheduler
```

I'm grepping some thing like

```
grep "scheduler" file.txt
```

The output it is showing both lines, but I want only single line
like:

```
-name: scheduler
```

Is there any way to limit it in `grep` (or any similar tool) to the exact pattern?

Comment: text file has different blocks not only scheduler

Comment: just simplified now ... their are two lines with same pattern but i want only such pattern which i pass

Comment: Do you know about `man grep`?

Comment: i have tried -e ,-x all from man ...  i didnt get the preffered o/p ..if you know help me

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198419/how-to-tell-grep-w-what-characters-make-up-words), grep considers words to be made up from alphanumeric characters and underscore. Therefore `-` is treated as a word-break and `grep scheduler` matches the "scheduler-configuration", even if you use `grep -w`.

You could make up your own pattern, to match before and after "scheduler", which not only includes the opposite of alphanumeric and "_", but other characters, too.

```
grep -E '([^[:alnum:]_-]|^)scheduler([^[:alnum:]_-]|$)' file.txt
```

This will match for "scheduler" not surrounded by other alphanumeric characters, or "_" or "-"

Comment: `grep "scheduler$" file.txt` will match EOL if that's all you need.

Comment: @roblogic : this is working thanks for simple answer

Comment: @yugandhar please take your time and read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you might just want `scheduler` surrounded by white space or nothing:

```
$ grep -E '(^|[[:space:]])scheduler([[:space:]]|$)' file
- name: scheduler
```

Comment: can you explain the command

Comment: @codeholic24 I think my first sentence already does. What part of it is unclear?

Comment: instead of space , if i add `[[ :blank:]]` is it going to give same result .. blank indicates both space and tab right ?

Comment: a) probably yes in this case, and b) depends what you mean by "space" -  `[:blank:]` is blank char or tab only while `[:space:]` is that plus newline, formfeed, vertical-tab and other white space chars. I always use `[:space:]` unless I **need** to use `[:blank:]` to exclude other white space chars than blank or tab.

Comment: @codeholic24 I assume you meant if you add `[[:blank:]]`, not really `[[ :blank:]]` which would be a completely different set of characters.